# How to change default vhost config in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, cpanel, vhosts

I'm using Nginx and I'm having difficulties in setting up web hosting accounts via cPanel.
Every time I create a new account in WHM, it's automaticly creating the config file for the domain in the vhosts folder (/etc/nginx/vhosts).
The issue is that the default config file that is being created is damaged. For example:
*It's creating the access log in a folder that doesn't exists.
*It doesn't have proper PHP settings.

How can I edit the default vhosts file that's automaticly being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over more than 50 files, the correct file that is building the vhost files (on cpanel) is: **/scripts/createvhosts.py**

Comment: user2298995 yes this places the vhost file however it uses a template to do so.